# Replace end of multi HTML text with a few dots

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following mark-up:

```js
if ($('.replacetext').text().length > 20) {
  var linkText = $('.replacetext').text();
  $('.replacetext').html(linkText.substring(0, 20) + "...")
  $('.replacetext').on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("linkText :: ", linkText);
    $('.replacetext').html(linkText);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>
  <a class="replacetext" href="">I am a very long title and I need to be shortened And Also I am a very long title and I need to be shortened</a>
</h5>

<h5>
  <a class="replacetext" href="">I am a very long title and I need to be shortened And Also I am a very long title and I need to be shortened</a>
</h5>
```

How can I make it so that if the h5 text (h5 may be more then one) is above a certain number of characters, I get rid of the other characters and replace them with a "..."?

the problem with this code is it also replaces the text same at all h5 tags along with dots.

Comment: Have you considered CSS's [text-overflow: ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)?

Comment: yes, I have tried but not successfully fulfil my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up I would reconsider the use of the `a` tag. You don't have a link. Use something else. I'll leave that up to you.

Next, you want to store the original text. I will use data attributes for this.

Finally, you want to only update the text of the clicked element. We will use the `this` keyword to help out here.

```js
//Go through each long title
$('.replacetext').each(function() {
  //If long title
  if ($(this).text().length > 20) {
    //Store original string in data attribute  
    $(this).data("og", $(this).text());
    //Replace text
    $(this).html($(this).text().substring(0, 20) + "...")
  }
});

$('.replacetext').on("click", function(e) {
  //Stop the link going anywhere
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Original Text: " + $(this).data("og"));
  //Replace with the original
  $(this).text($(this).data("og"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>
  <a class="replacetext" href="">I am a very long title and I need to be shortened And Also I am a very long title and I need to be shortened</a>
</h5>

<h5>
  <a class="replacetext" href="">I am another very long title and I need to be shortened And Also I am a very long title and I need to be shortened</a>
</h5>

<h5>
  <a class="replacetext" href="">I am short</a>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [CSS text-overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: not a good solution want to do with javascript. like I use as above.

thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Add all these. To make in single line.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width:100px; // some width
```

To do in multi line which actually you asked.

```
#content{
overflow: hidden;
width:100px;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Please note that this multiline code is supported only in web-kit browsers for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a proof of concept and has many unhandled potential pitfalls, but you *could* recursively iterate the children of the element and truncate the text nodes.

***I'm not saying this is a good idea***. You'll run into whitespace complications and edge cases. Just saying it could be done this way in theory.

```js
const TEXT = 3;
const ELEMENT = 1;

function truncateElement (elem, maxlength) {
  let remaining = maxlength;
  
  [...elem.childNodes].forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeType === TEXT) {
      node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substr(0, remaining);
      remaining -= node.nodeValue.length;
    }
    else if (node.nodeType === ELEMENT) {
      truncateElement(node, remaining);
    }
  });
  
  if (!remaining) {
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('…'));
  }
}

document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => truncateElement(document.querySelector('h5'), 20)
  );
```

```html
<div class="demo">
<h5><a class="replacetext" href="">I am a very long title and I need to be shortened And Also I am a very long title and I need to be shortened</a></h5>
<button>Truncate to 20</button>
</div>
```